# Overriding superclass functions

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-2.7

The member variable `condition` should change from `"new"` to `"like new"` once `my_car.drive_car()` is called. However, this call still executes the `drive_car` function from the `class Car` superclass instead of `class ElectricCar`

- Am I missing something?
- Is there a more elegant way to override
  superclass functions?

```
    class Car(object):
            condition = "new"

            def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
                    self.model, self.color, self.mpg = model, color, mpg

            def drive_car(self):
                    self.condition = "used"

    class ElectricCar(Car):
            def __init__(self, battery_type, model, color, mpg):
                    self.battery_type = battery_type
                    super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(model, color, mpg)

            def drive_car(self):
                        self.condition = "like new"

    my_car = ElectricCar("Flux capacitor", "DeLorean", "silver", 88)

    print my_car.condition #Prints "New"
    my_car.drive_car()
    print my_car.condition #Prints "Used" instead of "Like New"
```

Comment: Nope, not here, this code works. Make sure you have your indentation correct. As posted here you are way inconsistent.

Comment: Thank you @MartijnPieters It won't work on my end but is there a more elegant way to override the 'def drive_car' in 'class ElectricCar'? It seems redundant to declare 'def drive_car' twice.

Comment: This code works for me as well.

Comment: Codecademy aye? ;) You can ask on their forums, they're pretty helpful

Comment: If you want to override the superclass, you have to write something. How is it not elegant? It took two lines? You don't have to define `drive_car` at all in `Car` if you don't want to, but then you're not overriding anything, and this is more error prone. Not really sure how it's redundant if each implementation does different things. Most procedural languages work this way.

Comment: @jozzas It's not elegant as it doesn't scale well, you have to write the exact same method for any subclass only to change an attribute. This could be generalized using a class variable to store the condition after driving (e.g. `_driven_condition`) - now there only needs to be one `drive_car` method which simply does `self.condition = self._driven_condition`; `Car` defines `_driven_condition = "used"` as the default and subclasses can define their own values by simply overriding this class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of inheritance is actually what is conventionally "good object oriented programming". While there are plenty of other ways, the method you are already using is the best way to do it.